# Inline Computation of Math Expressions in Eigen C++

Tags: matlab, expression, trigonometry, eigen

I am trying to convert the following MATLAB code to Eigen C++.

**MATLAB:**

```
yMATLAB = sin(2*pi*100*(0:N-1));
```

**Eigen C++**

```
Eigen::VectorXf t = Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, N - 1.0);
Eigen::VectorXf t1 = 2.0 * EIGEN_PI * 100.0 * t;
Eigen::VectorXf yEigen = t1.array().sin();
std::cout << yEigen;
```

However, I am getting incorrect values in `yEigen`. Could you please let me know what part of my Eigen code is incorrect?

My second question is, can I have inline math expressions for this computation similar to the MATLAB statement that does everything in just one line? Something like the following without defining temporary variables (I know this won't compile):

```
Eigen::VectorXf y = 
    Eigen::sin(2.0 * EIGEN_PI * 100.0 * Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, N - 1.0));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are computing with double precision in Matlab but with single precision in Eigen, so Matlab unsurprisingly will get more "accurate" results.
Compare this with the values you get from Eigen:

```
yMATLAB = sin(single(2*pi*100*(0:N-1)));
```

To write the expression in one line, I suggest using `Array` instead of `Vector` in the first place -- especially if you will primarily do element-wise math:

```
Eigen::ArrayXf y = Eigen::sin(2.0 * EIGEN_PI * 100.0 *
                            Eigen::ArrayXf::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, N - 1.0));
```

The return value `y` can be an `VectorXf` as well, if you like.
Just for reference the same with `ArrayXd` instead of `ArrayXf` (which should be nearly identical to what Matlab calculates): https://godbolt.org/z/Qn69ru

If for some reason you want to write `VectorXf::LinSpaced`, you need to place an `(...).array()` around the expression you want to take the sine from, e.g.:

```
Eigen::VectorXf y = 
    Eigen::sin(
        (2.0 * EIGEN_PI * 100.0 * 
                Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, N - 1.0)
        ).array());
```

For more information check out [Eigen's documentation about the `Array` class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you please elaborate on why you recommend `Array` instead of `Vector`?

Comment: could you please have a look at this post as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60158302/1227860 I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding `Array` vs `Vector` please read the page I linked to at the end of my answer. This is mostly nicer syntax (less `.array()` inside the code). After optimization, the compiler should generate the same code in both cases.