# Reshaping flat array to complex Eigen type

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I reshape `data` of size `1×2N` to a complex form in Eigen to a form a `P×Q` complex matrix, with `N` complex numbers, `P×Q=N`? In `data`, the real and imaginary parts are right next to each other. I would like to dynamically reshape `data` as the data can have different sizes. I am trying to prevent copying and just map the data to complex type.

```
int N = 9;
int P = 3;
int Q = 6;
float *data = new float[2*N];
for(int i = 0; i < 2*N; i++)
    data[i] = i + 1; // data = {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 17, 18};

Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcf> A(data, P, Q); // trying to have something like this.

// Desired reshaping:
// A = [
//      1 + 2i     7 + 8i     13 + 14i
//      3 + 4i     9 + 10i    15 + 16i
//      5 + 6i    11 + 12i    17 + 18i
//      ]
```

I tried to first convert `data` to a complex Eigen array (to ultimately convert to `MatrixXcf`), which does not work either:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXf> Arr(data, N); // this works
Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXcf> Arrc(A.data(), N); // trying to map data to an Eigen complex array.
```

Could `stride` in `Eigen::Map` be helpful?

The simplest solution is to loop through all the elements and convert `data` to an array of `std::complex<float> *datac = new std::complex<float>[N];`. I was wondering if Eigen can map `data` to `datac`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `P*Q` does not equal `N` in your example. And in the "desired output" you only have `Q/2` columns. Is this intended?

Comment: What chtz said. Also, you don't (necessarily) need to map to an `Array` before mapping to a `MatrixXcf`.

Comment: @chtz sorry for the confusion. I meant `2N` float numbers that form `N` complex numbers.

Comment: @AviGinsburg please see my comment to chtz regarding the number of elements. Would you give me an example? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please create and post a [mcve] with your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the MCVE answer ([online example](https://godbolt.org/z/fq4E-n)) with some extra examples of how you can use the stride to get different outcomes:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    int N = 9;
    int P = 3;
    int Q = 6;
    float *data = new float[20*N];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20*N; i++)
        data[i] = i + 1; // data = {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 170, 180};

    // Produces the output of the "Desired reshaping"
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcf> 
               A((std::complex<float>*)(data), P, P);
    std::cout << A << "\n\n";

    // Produces what you originally wrote (plus a cast so it works)
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcf>
               B((std::complex<float>*)(data), P, Q);
    std::cout << B << "\n\n";

    // Start each column at the 10xJ position
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcf, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<>> 
               C((std::complex<float>*)(data), P, Q, Eigen::OuterStride<>(10));
    std::cout << C << "\n\n";

    // Skip every other value
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcf, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<>> 
               D((std::complex<float>*)(data), P, Q, Eigen::InnerStride<>(2));
    std::cout << D << "\n\n";

    delete [] data;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> (1,2)   (7,8) (13,14)
>     (3,4)  (9,10) (15,16)
>     (5,6) (11,12) (17,18)
>
> (1,2)   (7,8) (13,14) (19,20) (25,26) (31,32)
>     (3,4)  (9,10) (15,16) (21,22) (27,28) (33,34)
>     (5,6) (11,12) (17,18) (23,24) (29,30) (35,36)
>
> (1,2)   (21,22)   (41,42)   (61,62)   (81,82) (101,102)
>       (3,4)   (23,24)   (43,44)   (63,64)   (83,84) (103,104)
>       (5,6)   (25,26)   (45,46)   (65,66)   (85,86) (105,106)
>
> (1,2) (13,14) (25,26) (37,38) (49,50) (61,62)
>     (5,6) (17,18) (29,30) (41,42) (53,54) (65,66)
>    (9,10) (21,22) (33,34) (45,46) (57,58) (69,70)

Comment: Thank you. The best example ever written on the internet for Eigen complex numbers.

Comment: Avi, can I have your thoughts whenever you get a chance on my question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60344631/1227860?

Comment: @AFP Sorry, not my area of expertise.